# Focus minutes part of time input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, input, time

Is it possible to select the minutes part of the time input using javascript?
Focus and select-methods select only hours.
StepUp/down does nothing to selection.
Sending tab or arrow key event is not possible.
I'm running out of ideas.

```js
e = document.getElementById('leet');
e.focus()
e.stepUp(1);
e.stepDown(1);
e.select()
```

```html
<input id="leet" type="time" value="13:37" step="60" />
```

Comment: It looks very nice!  For me, if I click hours, hours get selected, if I click minutes, minutes get selected.  From hours, tab moves me to minutes, and from minutes, shift-tab moves me to hours.  What am I missing?  Also, can you show your code?